# How to display checkbox with values in filter menu

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am adding columns dynamically in the kendo ui grid. I have added property filterable as true. When I click the filter icon, it opens the default context menu.

What I want is on click of filter icon, I want to display checkbox along with value.

How can I do this.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't find any solution yet, how can I do this. Any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

Try setting filterable to true & columnMenu to false.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this link from the official telerik documentation can help: [Checkbox filter menu filtering](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/checkbox-filter-menu) The main idea is to use the filterMenuInit event to insert custom templates for every column needed.